# Storing value in last iteration only

Tags: matlab

```
P=load('D.dat');
Q=load('R.txt');
Q1=Q(1:2501,1);

n=10
for i=1:1:n
    P1=P(2502*i+2:2502*(i+1),1);
    D=find(P1<0.00101);
    D1=D(1);  
    Q10=Q1(D(1))
end
```

I am trying to write value of Q10 in every iteration but it is only saving the last one. Can anyone please help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Mattew Pope answer is correct. Please remember to always post a working example. For more complex questions it wouldn't be possible to answer correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your assignment to `Q10(i)=Q1(D(1))`. Then you also should preallocate the array before your loop with `Q10 = zeros(n,1);`.